# Jolt transfer elements from child array to parent

Tags: arrays, jolt

Here i was trying merge elements from 2 child arrays in to its parent one and leave the other one and move the second array to two levels up.

Is there a way to change value on condition, like in the input below,
parties.party.sno ="1" , can this updated as parties..sno='Y'

input:

```
{
  "Parties": [
    {
      "party": {
        "partyId": "100005767",
        "sno": 1,
        "fn": "Th1mas",
        "ln": "Edison",
        "emails": [
          {
            "emailAddress": "jkjk@ui.com"
          }
        ],
        "addresses": [
          {
            "zip": ""
          }
        ],
        "shealth": [
          {
            "stcd": "TN",
            "lno": "1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "seq": {
        "typeCd": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "person": {
    "first_name": "Th1mas",
    "middle_initial": "Edison",
    "last_name": "",
    "email_address": "jkjk@ui.com",
     "pinCode": ""
  },
  "shealth": {
    "statecd": "ON"   
  },
  //this is the seq no from party.sno
  "primary": "Y",    
  "typeCd": "1"
}
```

tried spec like this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Parties": {
        "*": {
          "party": {
            "emails": {
              "*": {
                "emailAddress": "[&1].email_address",
                "@(2,fn)": "[&1].first_name",
                "@(2,ln)": "[&1].last_name"
              }
            },
            "addresses": {
              "*": {
                "zip": "[&1].pinCode"
              }
            },
            "shealth": {
              "*": {
                "stcd": "[&1].statecd"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This spec works,

```
      "party": {
        "sno": {
          "1": {
            "#Y": "primary"
          }
        },
```

Try applying the condition from the current level,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Parties": {
        "*": {
          "party": {
            "sno": {
              "1": {
                "#Y": "primary"
              }
            },
            "emails": {
              "*": {
                "emailAddress": "person.email_address",
                "@(2,fn)": "person.first_name",
                "@(2,ln)": "person.last_name"
              }
            },
            "addresses": {
              "*": {
                "zip": "person.pinCode"
              }
            },
            "shealth": {
              "*": {
                "stcd": "shealth.statecd"
              }
            }
          },
          "seq": {
            "typeCd": "typeCd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. this works great!. if i add one more array to the input , then the ouput shows all values in single array but not individual arrays.. i mean like this   "first_name" : [ "Th1mas", "Thomas" ] instead of first_name" : "Th1mas", in first array and firstname:  "Thomas"  in second array. do i need add anything to spec for that

Comment: to be more clear, its like this {
   "person" : {
    "first_name" : [ "Th1mas", "Th1mas" ]} } instead of {"person":{ "first_name" :  "Th1mas"}, "perspn" :{ "first_name" :  "Th1mas"}}